# MS Access 2003: Check if data is within range from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, Table A with the hours, and Table B to have Grade, and minimum Hour required

What I'm trying to do is to assign TableB.Grade to TableA depending on how much hours each record has.

Example:

TableA

```
Name        Hours       
Person A     205
Person B     105
Person C     400
```

Table B

```
Grade       HoursRequired
1              0
2              100
3              200
4              300
```

My expected report

```
Name      Hours     Grade
Person A    105     2
Person B    205     3
Person C    400     4
```

Any advise on the SQL coding or restructuring of table would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @Andomar's suggestion.  However, if subqueries confuse you, you could revise TableB like this:

```
Grade low_end   high_end
1           0         99
2         100        199
3         200        299
4         300 2147483647
```

Then use this query:

```
SELECT a.person_name, a.hours, b.Grade
FROM TableA AS a, TableB AS b
WHERE (((a.hours) Between [b].[low_end] And [b].[high_end]))
ORDER BY a.person_name;
```

Name is a reserved word so I re-named your Name field to person_name.

Comment: Thanks so much! I previously had to export the report out to excel and use marco to get the result!

Comment: @user589343 You're welcome.  Re reserved words, visit http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html Mr. Browne also has a "Database Issue Checker Utility" available from that page.  By using it you can avoid numerous issues which can otherwise come back to bite you in the butt later on.  Check it out!

Comment: another question, tableA.hour is acutally a sum of hours from multiple rows from multiple join, and i have no idea on how to assign it to be A.house, what should i do?

Comment: @KenC Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking now.  Maybe show us the SQL for the multiple join which produces sum of hours.

Comment: select NameInfo.PersonName, NZ(A.Hour)+NZ(B.Hour)+NZ(C.Hour) as TotalHours 
from ((Nameinfo left join TableA A on NameInfo.PersonName=A.PersonName) 
left join TableB B on NameInfo.personName=B.PersonName)
left join TableB C on NameInfo.personName=C.PersonName

Comment: and my question was.. how do I turn the TotalHours into R.TotalHours so it can be recognized in the sub query?

Comment: @KenC Sorry I'm still lost.  Post this issue as a separate new question ... I think you'll get better exposure that way.  Right now it's buried in the comments and I don't know how many people will see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery:

```
select  A.Name
,       A.Hours
,       (
        select  top 1 grade 
        from    TableB B 
        where   B.HoursRequired <= A.Hours 
        order by 
                B.HoursRequired DESC
        ) as Grade
from    TableA A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Andomar, would be great if you can help me with my extension of the question! I posted it to the 2nd reply at @HansUp.