# check if multiple values are within corresponding (multiple) ranges in 1 query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Going off of this question from a few years back: [MS Access 2003: Check if data is within range from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796582/ms-access-2003-check-if-data-is-within-range-from-another-table#)

What would I do if I want to check if multiple data is within multiple ranges in one query? I'm trying to find the points per test that a person took. I have different ranges for each test since one test may be out of 100, while another only out of 10.

Would I have to create many queries using the answer in the question linked above and combine or is there an easier way?

Table A:

```
Name        Test1_Score    Test2_Score     Test3_Score        
Person A     205           98              5 
Person B     105           88              8
Person C     400           89              10
```

Table B:

```
Points       Test1_GradeReq    Test2_GradeReq     Test3_GradeReq
1              0               0               0
2              300             30              1
3              300             70              2
4              400             100             3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gets the number of points for each test and each person:

```
select a.name, a.Test1_Score, a.Test2_Score, a.Test3_Score,
       sum(iif(test1_score <= test1_gradeReq, 1, 0)) - 1 as Test1_Points,
       sum(iif(test2_score <= test2_gradeReq, 1, 0)) - 1 as Test2_Points,
       sum(iif(test3_score <= test3_gradeReq, 1, 0)) - 1 as Test3_Points
from TableA a, -- cross join
     TableB b
group by a.name, a.Test1_Score, a.Test2_Score, a.Test3_Score
```

It assumes that the points increment by one for each step.